# Is there a way to delete an ACC issue via API?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-construction-cloud

I've tried to call the `PATCH projects/{projectId}/issues/{issueId}` endpoint passing `deleted: true` and received a schema validation error, deleted is a read only field:

[image: Error Image]

So is there a way to delete an issue via API? I searched the documentation and found nothing.